# Java Sentence Analysis Check

Tags: java, string, text

Well, my teacher gave me an homework with java. He wants a program which analyses a sentence. I wrote the codes however it does not function. What did i do wrong can you just check it? (Well, i gave my hours to learn java by my own and to write these codes, so it means a lot to me!)

For page Ödev1.java ==>

```
package Ödev1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ödev1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a sentence");
        System.out.print(input);
      odev1 cumle = new odev1();
        cumle.analiz();
    }
}
```

For page odev1.java  ==>

```
package odev1;

public class odev1 {
    String input;
    int characters;
    int words;
    int gaps;
    int lowerletters;
    int capitalletters;
    int vowels;
    int sibilancies;

    public odev1(int characters, int words, int gaps, int lowerletters, int capitalletters, int vowels, int sibilancies) {
        this.characters = characters;
        this.words = words;
        this.gaps = gaps;
        this.lowerletters = lowerletters;
        this.capitalletters = capitalletters;
        this.vowels = vowels;
        this.sibilancies = sibilancies;
    }

  public void analysis()
  {
characters=input.length();
       char[] array = input.toCharArray();
int n=0;
for(int a=0;a<characters;a++) {
do{
n=n+1;
}while(array[a]!='0'); }
words=characters-n;
gaps=words-1;
capitalletters=0;
lowerletters=0;
for(int b=0;b<characters;b++) {
     if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(b))) capitalletters++;
     if (Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(b))) lowerletters++; }
vowels=0;
for(int c=0; c< input.length();c++) {
    switch(input.charAt(c)) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'ı':    
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'ö':
        case 'u':
        case 'ü':
            vowel++;
            break;            }
}
sibilancies=characters-gaps-vowels;
System.out.println("Count of characters="+characters);
System.out.println("Count of words="+words);
System.out.println("Count of gaps="+gaps);
System.out.println("Count of capital letters="+capitalletters);
System.out.println("Count of lower letters="+lowerletters);
System.out.println("Count of vowels="+vowels);
System.out.println("Count of sibilancies="+sibilancies);
}
}
```

Comment: You obviously seem to know how to copy/paste code into the question, so please do so for all the *relevant* code. Do not insert links to screenshots of code. --- *Hint:* Fix the indentations of your code to make it readable for human beings. And when pasting into question, indent an extra 4 spaces so the code will be correctly formatted here.

Comment: There is too much place to do that, my code is readable, why you think like that?

Comment: I don't know what "there is too much place to do that" means. "Too little" might make sense, except that there is more than adequate space to indent your code. Indenting code to show the *structure* of the code makes it more readable and less prone to errors. That why I (and most others) think like that. As for links to screenshots, it's just bad/lazy, and if the question becomes meaningless when linked server is down. Also, "it does not function" is a *lousy* description of your problem!!!!

Comment: To expand / explain what @Andreas has commented on.. Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, **select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.**

Comment: @Andreas ***"Do not insert links to screenshots of code."*** Such good advice I thought it was worth repeating, .. this time in **bold.**

Comment: Please also describe what the objective of your homework is. What should the program do?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson At last, thanks to you, i was able to copy/paste it. The program should analyse this one sentence's these properties: how many spaces(gaps), how many words, how many characters, how many lower letters(smallcaps), how many capital letters, how many vowels, how many sibilancies.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In this case, I suspect you might simply copy the `main(String[])` method into the `odev1` class to create an MCVE. ..

Comment: ,, 4) *"however it does not function"* **You'll need to be a lot more specific than that. What doesn't work? What output did you expect? What happened instead? We are not mind readers, and this is not a site where people will try to 2nd guess what needs fixing.** 5) From the code, and ignoring the option pane, this problem seems to have *nothing* to do with Swing. Question tags should represent the actual problem at hand, not every API peripherally used in the example!

Comment: 6) `String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bir cümle giriniz.");` and definitely start debugging this using hard code strings - like this `String input = "Mary had a little lamb.";`. Strings for which we can look at the input and predict the (unchanging) output.

Comment: Now i edited again and turned everything to English. @Andrew Thompson well the program asks an input and for example i enter "enough" , then the program just writes "enough" as the output. It does not analyse properties of the input that i enter!!

Comment: *"i enter "enough""* So hard code `"enough"` & we can all see it fail in the exact same way! The point(1) of making an MCVE is to make it as easy as practical to replicate the problem in our IDEs. 1) Or at least an important one of the *many* points.

Comment: What i enter as input doesnt matter. Whatever i write, the result is same. Can you please tell me which part is wrong, and what to do about it?

Comment: BTW - I just tried compiling the `odev1` class and got a compiler error on `vowel++;`. Where is it defined? No, scrap that.. I don't care enough to play 20 questions. Instead, once you think you have (**properly formatted**) code that you think is an MCVE, paste the class in a new project in your IDE, compile it and run it! The MCVE for a run-time problem should compile cleanly with no changes. It should run to demonstrate the faulty behaviour. ..

Comment: .. Note also that besides changing the nomenclature of the variables (good call on doing that, BTW) it is not strictly necessary to translate all code strings to English, unless they contain instructions on how to test the code.

Comment: What is MCVE? I just feel as terrible as you cant imagine :( I feel like i am nothing, i am just an idiot desperate newbie

Comment: *"What is MCVE?"* Like I mentioned in an earlier comment - [mcve]. *"I just feel as terrible as you cant imagine :( I feel like i am nothing, i am just an idiot desperate newbie"* We've all been newbies & felt like that. With time & experience, the feeling will happen ..less often. ;)

Comment: The reception might’ve been a bit harsh, but I hope it didn’t discourage you from asking for help. With questions like these I think you should always describe exactly how it’s working incorrectly and what the correct outcome should be. Translating your code to English does usually help since that’s the lingua franca on this particular site. I don’t think the [“How do I ask a good question?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page has been mentioned yet. I suggest you take a bit of time to read through it and we’ll be happy to help with your future questions! :)

Comment: Thank you, you are kind and helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is confuse, but for what I understood, you want to analyse a certain phrase.

First, the constructor of the class that handles the analyse must receive the `String` to analyse, since it is it's job. (Every class has a job, the result it's obtained from the classes methods).

Second, there is a convention on Java naming, and for classes the names start with capital letter. Check this document from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

So, the class should be something like this:

```java
public class Odev1 {

    private final String phase;

    public Odev1( String phrase ) {
        this.phrase = phrase;
    }

    //Remaining code...
}
```

As for the analyse itself there is several things that you should have in mind:

First, you don't have to to create an array of `char` from the `String`, you can just get the `char` directly with the `String`'s `charAt( int index )` method.

Second, when you have a for-loop, you can use the same leters, since the variables are local and therefor they won't be visible out of the for-loop

Third, when you construct a loop, you must make sure that you can break out of the loop. As an example, you wrote:

```java
int n=0;
for(int a=0;a<characters;a++) {
    do{
        n=n+1;
    }while(array[a]!='0'); 
}
words=characters-n;
```

Just here you have an infinite loop. Why are you in a do-while looping over the same `char`? Follow this:
`int n = 0;` => `int a=0;` => `do` => `n = n + 1` -> `n = 1` => condition `while` => `array[a]!='0'` -> `true` => repeat `do-while` loop... Forever...

Instead, you could iterate over the `String` and use `if-else` conditions to analyse it. Something like this:

```java
int n=0;
boolean isWord = false; //Use it to track the letters
boolean isSpace = false;
for(int i=0;i<characters;i++) {
    char charToAnalyse = input.getCharAt( i );

    if( charToAnalyse == ' ' ) { //Taking the simple case where you don't have breaklines
        isSpace = true;
        isWord = false;
    }
    else {
        isSpace = false;
        if( !isWord ) {
            isWord = true; //once it is counted, we should avoid recount.
            n++; //Its is the same as n = n + 1;
        }
    }
}
words=characters-n;
```

As a simpler way, you could use the `split(String regex)` method, but I gave the example above to help you understand.

```java
String[] wordsArray = input.split( " " );
words = wordsArray.lenght;
```

Forth, use `else-if` instead of constantly `if`'s if the inclusion of one means the exclusion of the remain. That is, in your code above you iterate over the letters to see if they are capital or not.

Also, you don't have to write a loop for each variable. Each character has several atributes, so just check them all in a single loop:

```java
int capitalletters = 0;
int lowerletters = 0;
int vowel = 0;

for(int i=0;i<characters;i++) {
    char charToAnalyse = input.charAt(i);

    if (Character.isUpperCase( charToAnalyse )) { 
        capitalletters++; 
    }
    else if (Character.isLowerCase( charToAnalyse  )){ 
        lowerletters++; 
    }
    //Imagine if there were many if statement and the condition 
    //was already true in the first...

    //count vowels;
    switch( charToAnalyse  ) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'ı':    
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'ö':
        case 'u':
        case 'ü':
            vowel++;
        break; //You can omit this one if it is at the end;
    }

}
```

In the end, to use the class `Odev1`, just do:

```java
Odev1 cumle = new Odev1( input );
cumle.analyse();
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: *"but I gave the example above to help you understand."* Nice work. Plus one for your comprehensive answer with explanations.

Comment: It really helped me! You are awesome awesome awesome, thank you <3 :D